# Closing streams in the middle of pipelines

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

When I execute this code which opens a lot of files during a stream pipeline:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Files.find(Paths.get("JAVA_DOCS_DIR/docs/api/"),
            100, (path, attr) -> path.toString().endsWith(".html"))
        .map(file -> runtimizeException(() -> Files.lines(file, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)))
        .map(Stream::count)
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
}
```

I get an exception:

```java
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /long/file/name: Too many open files
```

The problem is that `Stream.count` does not close the stream when it is done traversing it. But I don't see why it shouldn't, given that it is a terminal operation. The same holds for other terminal operations such as `reduce` and `forEach`. `flatMap` on the other hand closes the streams it consists of.

The documentation tells me to use a try-with-resouces-statement to close streams if necessary. In my case I could replace the `count` line with something like this:

```java
.map(s -> { long c = s.count(); s.close(); return c; } )
```

But that is noisy and ugly and could be a real inconvenience in some cases with big, complex pipelines.

So my questions are the following:

1. Why were the streams not designed so that terminal operations close the streams they are working on? That would make them work better with IO streams.
2. What is the best solution for closing IO streams in pipelines?

---

`runtimizeException` is a method that wraps checked exception in `RuntimeException`s.

Comment: WHy don't you just use a standard foreach loop? In this case it is better suited than streams

Comment: @fge: This is just an example. I'm interested in how to solve this generally.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two issues here: handling of checked exceptions such as `IOException`, and timely closing of resources.

None of the predefined functional interfaces declare any checked exceptions, which means that they have to be handled within the lambda, or wrapped in an unchecked exception and rethrown. It looks like your `runtimizeException` function does that. You probably also had to declare your own functional interface for it. As you've probably discovered, this is a pain.

On the closing of resources like files, there was some investigation of having streams be closed automatically when the end of the stream was reached. This would be convenient, but it doesn't deal with closing when an exception is thrown. There's no magic do-the-right-thing mechanism for this in streams.

We're left with the standard Java techniques of dealing with resource closure, namely the **try-with-resources** construct introduced in Java 7. TWR really wants to have resources be closed at the same level in the call stack as they were opened. The principle of "whoever opens it has to close it" applies. TWR also deals with exception handling, which usually makes it convenient to deal with exception handling and resource closing in the same place.

In this example, the stream is somewhat unusual in that it maps a `Stream<Path>` to a `Stream<Stream<String>>`. These nested streams are the ones that aren't closed, resulting in the eventual exception when the system runs out of open file descriptors. What makes this difficult is that files are opened by one stream operation and then passed downstream; this makes it impossible to use TWR.

An alternative approach to structuring this pipeline is as follows.

The `Files.lines` call is the one that opens the file, so this has to be the resource in the TWR statement. The processing of this file is where (some) `IOExceptions` get thrown, so we can do the exception wrapping in the same TWR statement. This suggests having a simple function that maps the path to a line count, while handling resource closing and exception wrapping:

```
long lineCount(Path path) {
    try (Stream<String> s = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {
        return s.count();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
    }
}
```

Once you have this helper function, the main pipeline looks like this:

```
Files.find(Paths.get("JAVA_DOCS_DIR/docs/api/"),
           100, (path, attr) -> path.toString().endsWith(".html"))
     .mapToLong(this::lineCount)
     .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: But, of course, you can also put the contents of the helper method into a lambda expression. It would get compiled to the same bytecode, the only difference is that the synthetic helper method will be `static`.

Comment: In conclusion, I take it that this solution is to put the processing of the stream of lines from each file into a single pipeline step. In that way they can be closed reliably. This requires that you structure the whole pipeline around that and can be a bit of an inconvenience. But maybe it's the only right way.

Comment: @Lii Yes that seems to be the most reliable technique we have today (Java 8). It's possible that there are others, though I think once a resource has been returned by its caller, it's really hard to ensure that it's closed properly, especially in the case of exceptions. The streams API definitely needs work in this area.

Comment: @Stuart Mark: Thanks for your clarifications. I added a second attempt to my answer on creating a general utility method for doing exactly what you propose. Please tell me you can spot any problems with it!

Comment: "None of the predefined functional interfaces declare any checked exceptions" -> `java.util.concurrent.Callable` is a functional interface and it declared as `throws Exception`.

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to create a utility method that reliably closes streams in the middle of a pipeline.

This makes sure that each resource is closed with a try-with-resource-statement but avoids the need for a custom utility method, and is much less verbose than writing the try-statement directly in the lambda.

With this method the pipeline from the question looks like this:

```
Files.find(Paths.get("Java_8_API_docs/docs/api"), 100,
        (path, attr) -> path.toString().endsWith(".html"))
    .map(file -> applyAndClose(
        () -> Files.lines(file, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1),
        Stream::count))
    .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

The implementation looks like this:

```
/**
 * Applies a function to a resource and closes it afterwards.
 * @param sup Supplier of the resource that should be closed
 * @param op operation that should be performed on the resource before it is closed
 * @return The result of calling op.apply on the resource 
 */
private static <A extends AutoCloseable, B> B applyAndClose(Callable<A> sup, Function<A, B> op) {
    try (A res = sup.call()) {
        return op.apply(res);
    } catch (RuntimeException exc) {
        throw exc;
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrapped in applyAndClose", exc);
    }
}
```

<sup>(Since resources that need to be closed often also throw exceptions when they are allocated non-runtime exceptions are wrapped in runtime exceptions, avoiding the need for a separate method that does that.)</sup>

Comment: Interesting, kind of a like a pluggable try-with-resources. Presumably `ThrowingSupplier` is declared to throw `Exception`. While it's cool, it's unclear whether this is actually better than just writing a specific helper function. But time and experience will tell. Good to have it around in the toolbox though; it might come in handy.

Comment: With Project Lambda the time has come, for good and for bad, for user defined custom statements in Java.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to call `close()` in this stream operation, which will cause all underlying close handlers to be called.

Better yet, would be to wrap your whole statement in a *try-with-resources* block, as then it will automagically call the close handler.

This may not be possibility in your situation, this means that you will need to handle it yourself in some operation. Your current methods may not be suited for streams at all.

It seems like you indeed need to do it in your second `map()` operation.

Answer (score 3):

The *close* of the interface *AutoCloseable* should only be called once. See the documentation of [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) for more information.

If *final* operations would close the stream automatically, *close* might be invoked twice. Take a look at the following example:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
    lines.count();
}
```

As it is defined right now, the *close* method on *lines* will be invoked exactly once. Regardless whether the *final* operation completes normally, or the operation is aborted with in *IOException*. If the stream would instead be closed implicitly in the *final* operation, the *close* method would be called once, if an *IOException* occurs, and *twice* if the operation completes successfully.

Comment: This might be a plausible explanation. The documentation however only says repeated calls to `close` might have visible side effects, not that it is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative which uses another method from `Files` and will avoid leaking file descriptors:

```
Files.find(Paths.get("JAVA_DOCS_DIR/docs/api/"),
    100, (path, attr) -> path.toString().endsWith(".html"))
    .map(file -> runtimizeException(() -> Files.readAllLines(file, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).size())
    .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Unlike your version, it will return an `int` instead of a `long` for the line count; but you don't have files with that many lines, do you?

Comment: I am really more interested in the general case of closing streams in pipelines, `count` is only an example. One disadvantage with `readAllLines` is that it has to keep all lines in memory at the same time.

Comment: Do you mean close the streams or the resources that the stream could potentially handle?

Comment: I want to close the resources. I wanted to do this by closing the stream so that the stream close the resource, but I don't find a nice way to do that.

Comment: Well, you have the problem that `Files.lines()` doesn't give you control over the `Path`; it handles opening/closing the file by itself.

Comment: The stream returned by `Files.lines` actually works fine and closes the file when it is closed itself. The problem is how to close the stream in an elegant way in this case.