# Do terminal operations close the stream?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

`dirPath` contains 200k files. I want to read them one by one and do some processing. The following snippet causes `java.nio.file.FileSystemException: dirPath/file-N Too many open files`. Isn't the terminal operation `forEach()` supposed to close the open stream (i.e. the open file) before moving to the next one? In other words, do I have to add try-with-resources for the streamed files?

```
Files.list(dirPath)
     .forEach(filePath -> {
              Files.lines(filePath).forEach() { ... }
              });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing streams in the middle of pipelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921623/closing-streams-in-the-middle-of-pipelines)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No `forEach` does not close the stream (created by `Files.list` or `Files.lines`). It is documented in the javadoc, for example for [`Files.list`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-):

> The returned stream encapsulates a Reader. If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.

Answer (score 8):

A nested `forEach` is the wrong tool, in most cases.

The code

```
Files.list(dirPath).forEach(filePath -> Files.lines(filePath).forEach(line -> { ... });
```

can and *should* be replaced by

```
Files.list(dirPath).flatMap(filePath -> Files.lines(filePath)).forEach(line -> { ... });
```

or well, since it’s not that easy in this case:

```
Files.list(dirPath).flatMap(filePath -> {
    try { return Files.lines(filePath);}
    catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
}).forEach(line -> {  });
```

as a side-effect, you get the following for free:

#### [`Stream.flatMap(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

> Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream.

So that’s the preferred solution. Or well, to make it entirely correct:

```
try(Stream<Path> dirStream = Files.list(dirPath)) {
    dirStream.flatMap(filePath -> {
        try { return Files.lines(filePath);}
        catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
    }).forEach(line -> { });
}
```

Comment: I think you've misread the docs for flatMap. flatMap takes a function which itself returns many streams; what flatMap does is ensure that those streams, returned from the function passed to flatMap, are closed when the results of those streams are flattened into the stream that flatMap returns. flatMap is no different from map with respect to the stream it is applied to.

Comment: (Or I guessed you figured that out from your subsequent edit. :) )

Comment: @BarryKelly I never said that `flatMap` had an effect on the outer stream. The single outer stream wasn’t the OP’s problem, it was the 200k streams produced by the function passed to `flatMap`. So I provided a solution which closes these 200k streams. But since leaving that one stream open still isn’t a clean behavior, I provided the complete code with my edit.