# Does Files.list() cause resource leakage or does not close the stream?

Tags: java-8, try-catch, java-stream, fileutils

Files.list() cause IOException on FileUtils.deleteDirectory() using Stream

Hi all, I was doing some junit test I notice that certain tests was falling for unknowing reason (if the test was run individually they all work)

I notice that I was not able to access the folders manipulated by my class (in windows) the folder was not deleted and in windows if I try open/delete win error popup, apparently  something was holding the folder and preventing it from been deleted

After few hard hours I found that *if you do not put inside a try() the code File.list will continue holding the the folder*, due so I was not able to delete.

```
package java.nio.file;
package org.apache.commons.io;
```

Causes problems:

```
String id = Files.list(tempDir.toPath())
        .map(Path::toFile)
        .filter(File::isDirectory)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("data is missing " + tempDir.getAbsolutePath()))
        .getName();
```

but if you wrap in a try all works fine

```
String Id;
try (Stream<Path> sFiles = Files.list(tempDir.toPath())) {
    sipId = sFiles
            .map(Path::toFile)
            .filter(File::isDirectory)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("data is missing" + tempDir.getAbsolutePath()))
            .getName();
}
```

This runs after my the class with the code above is finished

```
if (manifestFolder.exists()) {
   try {
        FileUtilenter code heres.deleteDirectory(manifestFolder);
   } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

**My question is why do I need to wrap in a try the Files.list() ? 
There is any other simple way to get it done ?**

Comment: or maybe recommend a best practice

Comment: wait are you wondering why using a `try with resource` is actually good? because if closes the resources that otherwise are left open?

Comment: hi @eugene thanks for your reply, so basically as far as i undestood i need to put it inside a try for it get closed, and do you know if there any other simplistic way to do this without having to put in a try?

Comment: and for to be fair i don't understand why it does not get closed, i though it would be done automatically

Comment: this is the easiest way, if you would have to do it manually, you would probably get in wrong on some first attempts...

Comment: Hi Philippe, I know you are still fairly new to Stack Overflow but please, please, pretty please, try to make actual sentences, use punctuation, proofread yourself… If nobody wants to read your question, it's unlikely to get answered. You will get much better results if you put more effort into it. As a side effect, you will get more upvotes, and thus more visibility. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center, and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) by Jon Skeet.

Comment: @DidierL - thanks for your suggestion, I edited the question, hopefully will be better to understand

Comment: Thanks, @Philippe, that's much better. I think your question is already answered in the above one actually. I hope this helps.

Comment: There is also [Do terminal operations close the stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997240/do-terminal-operations-close-the-stream)

Comment: @DidierL - Brilliant that really helped, thank you