# Need to count the number of files located within each zip file in a directory folder in JAVA

Tags: java, file, directory, path, zip

I have a folder which has a series of Zip files within it. I am trying to iterate through the folder and count the number of files that are in each zip file. I have created two pieces of code, I am just not sure how to put them together to get my desired results. Both codes are placed into try/catch blocks and they both work perfectly independently. This is using Eclipse, written in Java.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
 
public class KZF {
 
       public static void main(String[] args) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
             // Try/Catch Block counts the number of files within a given zip file
             try {
 
                    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(
                           "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Temp\\AllKo\\Policy.zip");
 
                    int NumberOfFiles = zipFile.size() - 1;
                    // String name = zipFile.getName();
                    Path path = Paths
                           .get("C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Temp\\AllKo\\Policy.zip");
                    Path filename = path.getFileName();
 
                    System.out.print("The number of files in: ");
                    // System.out.print(name);
                    System.out.print(filename.toString());
                    System.out.print(" are: ");
                    System.out.print(NumberOfFiles + " file(s)");
 
                    zipFile.close();
 
             }
 
             catch (IOException ioe) {
 
                    System.out.println("Error opening zip file" + ioe);
             }
 
             // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             // Creates list of every file specified folder
 
             
              String dirLocation = "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Temp\\AllKo";
             
               try { List<File> files = Files.list(Paths.get(dirLocation))
              .map(Path::toFile) .collect(Collectors.toList());
             
               files.forEach(System.out::println);
             
               } catch(IOException e) { Error }
             
 
       }
 
}
```

Comment: The first part for counting the files within a ZIP file should probably be a separate method with `Path` parameter and `int` return type which you then call from the loop over the ZIP files in the directory. Note however that `ZipFile.size()` returns the number of entries, and ZIP files may also contain directory (i.e. non-file) entries. Additionally calling `Files.list(...).collect(...)` does not close the `Stream` created by `Files.list(...)` see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/26997240; you would have to use a `try-with-resources` with `Files.list(...)` as resource.

Answer (score 0):

You must be careful about opening/closing streams, so you can try something like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class KZF
{
    static int findNumberOfFiles(File file) {
        try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file)) {
            return zipFile.stream().filter(z -> !z.isDirectory()).count();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    static String createInfo(File file) {
        int tot = findNumberOfFiles(file);
        return (file.getName() + ": " + (tot >= 0 ? tot + " files" : "Error reading zip file"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String dirLocation = "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Temp\\AllKo";
        try (Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get(dirLocation))) {
            files
            .filter(path -> path.toFile().isFile())
            .filter(path -> path.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip"))
            .map(Path::toFile)
            .map(KZF::createInfo)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the help. I tried this code, but when testing, it works for some of the zip files, but for other files, it outputs the incorrect number of files. Do you know what could be causing that issue?

Comment: Try to replace the "zipfile.stream().filter...." with a loop showing the type and name of file, letting it work only on wrongly evaluated zip files. E.g.

    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipFile.entries()
    int i=0;   
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      ZipEntry entry = e.nextElement();
      System.out.println(entry.isDirectory()? "D:": "F:"+entry.getName());
      i++;
     }
    return I;

Comment: Thank you so much! This did work. But now I have another question. The count numbers being printed need to be placed into a database table in Microsoft SQL server. What would you suggest is the easiest way to do so?

Comment: @JsohLearner there are a lot of approaches: you can use an ORM like Hibernate, and/or Spring, and/or JPA, etc. If you need a quick&dirty approach, just use a low-level JPA approach. See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html for further details.