# Do terminal operations on streams close the source?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following code:

```
Path directory = Paths.get(/* some directory */);
Files.list(directory).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Does a terminal operation (like `forEach`) close the underlying file that has been opened?

Refer to the relevant parts of the javadoc of [Files.list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-):

> The returned stream encapsulates a DirectoryStream. If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.

If it doesn't call `Stream.close()`, what would then be the best alternative to call it while producing maintainable code?

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997240/do-terminal-operations-close-the-stream?rq=1 with the exception of also asking what "counter-measures" to take.

Comment: Also similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921623/closing-streams-in-the-middle-of-pipelines), which has a long answer describing the motivation for this behaviour.

Comment: Strongly disagree with the delete vote. It's useful for this question to exist closed, as a pointer to the canonical answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Terminal operators do NOT close the stream automatically. Consider this code:

```
Stream<Path> list = Files.list(directory).onClose(() -> System.out.println("Closed"));
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This does NOT print "Closed".

However, the following does print "Closed":

```
try (Stream<Path> list = Files.list(directory).onClose(() -> System.out.println("Closed"))) {
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

So the best way to do it is to use the try-with-resources mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

So a quick-check reveals that `forEach` does not close the `DirectoryStream`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 * Created for http://stackoverflow.com/q/27381329/1266906
 */
public class FileList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path directory = Paths.get("C:\\");
        try {
            Stream<Path> list = Files.list(directory).onClose(() -> System.out.println("Close called"));
            list.forEach(System.out::println);
            // Next Line throws "java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed" even though "Close called" was not printed
            list.forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
        }

        // The mentioned try-with-resources construct
        try (Stream<Path> list = Files.list(directory)) {
            list.forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
        }

        // Own helper-method
        try {
            forEachThenClose(Files.list(directory), System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
        }
    }

    public static <T> void forEachThenClose(Stream<T> list, Consumer<T> action) {
        try {
            list.forEach(action);
        } finally {
            list.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I see the two presented mitigations:

1. use try-with-resources as stated in the `Files.list` JavaDoc
2. write your own helper-method which utilizes a finally-block

Which is more maintainable depends probably on how-many helper-methods you would need.