# Do I have to close terminated, streamed query results in a try-with-resources-block?

Tags: java, java-8, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

in the Spring Data JPA docs it says regarding streams:

> A Stream potentially wraps underlying data store specific resources and must therefore be closed after usage. You can either manually close the Stream using the close() method or by using a Java 7 try-with-resources block.

See: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming

If I process a stream with `forEach`, a count or another terminal operation, it should already be closed (and not be reused again) and I wouldn't have to wrap the stream in additional try-resources-block (given that my blocks don't throw any exception), or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Java APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) describe this topic as follows:

> Streams have a `BaseStream.close()` method and implement `AutoCloseable`, but nearly all stream instances do not actually need to be closed after use. Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel (such as those returned by `Files.lines(Path, Charset))` will require closing. Most streams are backed by collections, arrays, or generating functions, which require no special resource management. (If a stream does require closing, it can be declared as a resource in a try-with-resources statement.)

Also note the API for [`Files.lines(Path, Charset))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-):

> The returned stream encapsulates a `Reader.` If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's `close` method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.

Bottom line is: if the stream corresponds to a resource that, in normal scenarios need to be closed after use (like IO), use it in a try-with-resources statement.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the obvious point. That helped. Also, as I saw to late, there's that answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381329/do-terminal-operations-on-streams-close-the-source

Comment: To clarify: *Any* time a "resource" is used, you must use try-with-resources (or equivalent) to release it when done, even when using streams. Even if stream `forEach` closed at end, you must do it, otherwise you'll get resource leaks if an exception happens. Since `forEach` doesn't call `close()`, you definitely have to.