# Spring repository method which are returning Java 8 stream doesn't close JDBC connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, java-stream, spring-jdbc

I have a `Spring data` repository:

```
@Repository
interface SomeRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity, Long> {
    Stream<Entity> streamBySmth(String userId);
}
```

I am calling that method in some Spring bean:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
private void someMethod(){
    someRepository.streamBySmth("smth").forEach(this::callSomeMethod);
}
```

I am using MySQL database. And when I am running application after some successful method invocations it throws an exception:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Could not create connection to database server.
o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

It seems, that connection was not closed properly by Spring. If I have changed method return value to `List` from `Stream` it works correctly.

**UPDATE:**
Spring Boot version is 1.4.1.RELEASE

Comment: Have you tried calling `close` on the stream?

Comment: I have tried, it was not helped. Nevertheless, it is not correct behavior to close `Stream` manually.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with returning a `Stream` from a repository, but a `Stream` is lazy, so how would Spring otherwise know when to close the connection? `Stream` is an `AutoClosable` as well, so you could use it in a try-with-resources clause.

Comment: `Stream`s has ending operations, that means that you can not do anything else with Stream after them. `forEach` is one of such operations.

Comment: They have terminating operations, but that doesn't close the stream. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659872/do-i-have-to-close-terminated-streamed-query-results-in-a-try-with-resources-bl

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the [reference documentation clearly states](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming), `Stream`s need to be used with a try-with-resources block.

Also, make sure you keep a (read-only) transaction open for the time of the consumption of the stream by annotating the surrounding method with `@Transactional`. Otherwise the default settings apply and the resources are attempted to be freed on repository method return.

```
@Transactional
public void someMethod() {

  try (Stream<User> stream = repository.findAllByCustomQueryAndStream()) {
    stream.forEach(…);
  } 
}
```

Comment: It looks reasonable but it does not help us. I still have same error after several requests.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help again. I have tried to use `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` and also i have tried to `.close()` streams. Now it runs successfully 100 counts and fails. As i understand it means that new connection are opened on every request. Can it be a Spring bug?

Comment: Can you provide a sample reproducing your problem? There's a ticket with a problem described that sounds related [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-917) but that can be solved by following what I described above.

Answer (score 3):

Using @Transactional(readOnly = true) and public access modifier will solve the issue. Any other access modifier will not work.