# Spring Data repository: list vs stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

What are recommendations when to define method `list` and `stream` in Spring Data repository?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming

Example:

```
interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  List<User> findAllByLastName(String lastName);

  Stream<User> streamAllByFirstName(String firstName);                    
         
  // Other methods defined.
}
```

Please, note, here I am not asking about **Page**, **Slice** - they are clear to me, and I found their description in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters).

---

My assumption (am I wrong?):

1. Stream does not load all the records into Java Heap. Instead it loads `k` records into the heap and processes them one by one; then it loads another `k` records and so on.
2. List does load all the records into Java Heap at once.
3. If I need some background batch job (for example calculate analytics), I could use stream operation because I will not load all the records into the heap at once.
4. If I need to return a REST response with all the records, I will need to load them into RAM anyway and serialize them into JSON. In this case, it makes sense to load a list at once.

---

I saw that some developers collect the stream into a list before returning a response.

```
class UserController {

    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
        return new ResponseEntity(
                repository.streamByFirstName()
                        // OK, for mapper - it is nice syntactic sugar. 
                        // Let's imagine there is not map for now...
                        // .map(someMapper)  
                       .collect(Collectors.toList()), 
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

For this case, I do not see any advantage of Stream, using `list` will make the same end result.

Are then any examples when using `list` is justified?

Comment: 4. No you don't you can stream the result to the user instead of retrieving everything in one go, so it will reduce the memory pressure on the server.

Comment: Partially agree. If I return a stream to the user, and the user streams the data; then, yes, it reduces memory load on the server side. However, if it is an old REST API that returns a collection of records at once; it means I still have to render (serialize) JSON collection of records before returning it to the client.

Comment: No you don't. The collection is serialized into JSON, you can do this with a stream perfectly well and getting the same result. So the fact that you return `Collection<YourObject>` is only a trigger for Spring MVC to write it as such, you can do the same with a `Stream` and the client wouldn't notice the difference. Although it would require some (little) work on your side.

Comment: Using Stream, take into account https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015800/spring-repository-method-which-are-returning-java-8-stream-doesnt-close-jdbc-co

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### tl;dr

The primary difference in `Collection` VS `Stream` are the following two aspects:

1. **Time to first result** – when does the client code see the first element?
2. **The state of resources while processing** - in what state are underlying infrastructure resources while the stream is processed?

### Working with collections

Let's talk this through with an example. Let's say we need to read 100k `Customer` instances from a repository. The way you (have to) handle the result gives a hint at both of the aspects described above.

```
List<Customer> result = repository.findAllBy();
```

The client code will receive that list once *all* elements have been completely read from the underlying data store, not any moment before that. But also, underlying database connections *can* have been closed. I.e. e.g. in a Spring Data JPA application you will see the underlying `EntityManager` be closed and the entity detached unless you actively keep that in a broader scope, e.g. by annotating surrounding methods with `@Transactional` or using an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`. Also, you don't need to actively close the resources.

### Working with streams

A stream will have to be handled like this:

```
@Transactional
void someMethod() {

  try (Stream result = repository.streamAllBy()) {
    // … processing goes here
  }
}
```

With a `Stream`, the processing can start as soon as the first element (e.g. row in a database) arrives and is mapped. I.e. you will be able to already consume elements while others of the result set are still processed. That also means, that the underlying resources need to actively be kept open and as they're usually bound to the repository method invocation. Note how the `Stream` also has to actively be closed (try-with-resources) as it binds underlying resources and we somehow have to signal it to close them.

With JPA, without `@Transactional` the `Stream` will not be able to be processed properly as the underlying `EntityManager` is closed on method return. You'd see a few elements processed but an exception in the middle of the processing.

### Downstream usage

So while you theoretically can use a `Stream` to e.g. build up JSON arrays efficiently, it significantly complicates the picture as you need to keep the core resources open until you've written *all* elements. That usually means writing the code to map objects to JSON and writing them to the response manually (using e.g. Jackson's `ObjectMapper` and the `HttpServletResponse`.

### Memory footprint

While the memory footprint will likely improve, this mostly stems from the fact that you're like avoiding the intermediate creation of collections and additional collections in mapping steps (`ResultSet` -> `Customer` -> `CustomerDTO` -> JSON Object). Elements already processed *are not* guaranteed to be evicted from memory as they might be held onto for other reasons. Again, e.g. in JPA you'd have to keep the `EntityManager` open as it controls the resource lifecycle and thus all elements will stay bound to that `EntityManager` and will be kept around until *all* elements are processed.

Comment: Regarding the EntityManager holding on to the entities, `entityManager.detach(obj);` can be used to release the entity (ref: https://medium.com/predictly-on-tech/spring-data-jpa-batching-using-streams-af456ea611fc)

Answer (score 3):

A stream should be more memory efficient than a list but read-on.

I had a requirement to export some large logs to CSV. So I created a Stream method on the repository. I then used it to run a query, iterate one result at a time, writing a line to an output stream, rinse repeat.

So I thought I was fine, but unbeknownst to me, the database driver was snaffling results up in memory faster than I was writing them out. So the memory ballooned and with a million results piling up in memory the JVM ran out of memory and died.

So yes in theory it should be efficient, but you also have to annotate your driver with hints to throttle it.

In my case I had to use QueryHint annotations to stop it fetching more than 5000 records at a time, so if I was slow pushing the results it would pause until I started consuming what it had already fetched.

My code looked like this.

```
@Query("Select a from Log a where a.id >= :oldestId and a.timestamp >= :begin and a.timestamp <= :end order by a.timestamp asc")
@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.fetchSize", value="5000"))
Stream<Log> getLogs(long oldestId, Timestamp begin, Timestamp end);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Stream` and `Collection` both have Collection of Objects, but the problem with Collection and its implementations is that `Collection` implementation have all the elements in memory, actually `Stream` is introduced in Java8 to tackle this problem(and some other problems). Imagine what happened if you have `Collection` with infinite number of elements, Could you have `Collection` with infinite number of elements? sure you can't because no matter how large  your memory is, you will get out off memory exception at some point. but Stream does not have this problem you can have infinite number of elements with `Stream` because they are not stored in memory, they will be generated on demand.

Back to your question imagine what happen if you have many many records that have the `lastname` in your first query `findAllByLastName`? Sure you will get `OutOfMemoryError` exception but Stream solve this problem no matter how many record meet your criteria you won't get `OutOfMemoryError` exception.
`Stream` does not load object in memory it loads objects on demand, So it performs better on large result queries.

So the answer to your questions:

1. Yes, it loads elements to memory on demand so it reduces the amount of memory consumption and query calls to a database.
2. Yes, List Loads all record that meet criteria when you call that method.
3. Yes, if you want to iterate through your record that meet some criteria and do some processing job you should use Stream one.
4. This is the tricky one, somehow No, When you are using `WebFlux` and other similar approaches for reactive programming, I think it is better to go for the `Stream` one.

**Important note**: In case when you said some developers collect the stream into a list before returning a response,  They can boost their performance using WebFlux and return `Stream` itself. it is much better approach.

Comment: The fundamental statement that you won't run into an OOME is wrong. E.g. JPA will still hold on to all elements process in the current `EntityManager` and you'll see an OOME if the number of elements processed becomes to large.

Comment: @OliverDrotbohm so maybe detaching the entity from `EntityManager ` may help us. Am I wrong?