# Spring JPA Repositories with Stream<Entity>

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I fail to understand how `Stream<>` return type is different from `List<>` for a repository method.

I wrote a simple method below with fetch `size = 1`, but I ended up getting all the 4 records from the table, which is similar to the List<>. Am I missing something? Should it not fetch only 1 record as specified in the `HINT_FETCH_SIZE`. If it fetches 1 records, how the remaining **3 records are fetched?** How many database calls are done?

```
@QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "1"),
        @QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
        @QueryHint(name = HINT_READONLY, value = "true"), })
@Query("SELECT s FROM Customer s")
public Stream<Customer> findAllStream8();
```

Service:

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Customer> findAllStream(){
    try (Stream<Customer> streamCustomer = repository.findAllStream8()){
        return streamCustomer.collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Arrays.asList(new Customer("stream customer"));
}
```

Controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/customer/allStream")
public List<Customer> findAllCustomersStream(){
    return cs.findAllStream();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is greatly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63127616/13210306

About your code, the `HINT_FETCH_SIZE` is used to limit the number of items fetched in each iteration until it reaches all items. It will fetch 1 item for each iteration, in your case 4 iterations.

For limiting the number of returned items, you can use limit query by name (eg: findFirst() or findTop1()). Take a look here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

Or you can limit your query results by using `setMaxResults()`.

```java
criteria.setMaxResults(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

[baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-java-8#stream-api)

> Spring Data uses provider-specific implementation to stream the result
> (Hibernate uses ScrollableResultSet, EclipseLink uses
> ScrollableCursor). It reduces the amount of memory consumption and
> query calls to a database. Because of that, it's also much faster than
> two solutions mentioned earlier.

Check what hibernate states about that

[Query Streaming](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#jpql-api-stream)

> The Stream is closed automatically after calling the collect method,
> since there is no reason to keep the underlying JDBC ResultSet open if
> the Stream cannot be reused

Query Streaming is just a new mechanism invented to better allocate resources and memory.

In your example in the following line

```
 return streamCustomer.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

during collect you make it read all entities from database and collect them in a list. According to your preferences I would suspect that it goes 4 times in the database each time reading 1 row (1 Entity Customer)

If during stream you have skipped some elements as indicated in the query Streaming link from hibernate that I have posted above it wouldn't have read those from database.

So if you had `streamCustomer.skip(2).collect(Collectors.toList());`

it would have read only 2 elements from database and would have hit database 2 times. As you would have skipped 2 elements from stream it wouldn't need to bring those.

Also if you had
`streamCustomer.limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList());`

it would have read 3 entities from that stream and collected them to your List. So it would have hit database 3 times fetching 1 row (1 Customer entity) each time.

This is in my opinion how it is used to better allocate memory and resources.