Count files in folder, ignoring hidden files, ignoring nested folders, in Java
Simply counting files is turning out to be surprisingly difficult in Java.
I want to point to a folder, and count files found at the top level of that folder. Ignore hidden files, such as Unix-style names starting with a .. Ignore nested folders.
Example:
 Sales 
     Wine Sales 2024 
         .DS_Store
         Interim report.text
         Q1
             West region.text
             East region.text
         Q2
         Q3
         Q4

If I point to the folder named "Wine Sales 2024", I want to get a count of 1, for a count of files found directly in that folder. In this case, Interim report.text. I want to ignore the folders within. I do not want a recursive count of any documents found within those nested folders.
File#listFiles
I found the Question, Counting the number of files in a directory using Java. But that Question is actually asking about performance issues, and I do not care about performance issues. I have simple folders with maybe a dozen documents; I just want an easy way to get the count.
That Question has some awkward code that does not meet my basic criteria. This line:
new File(<directory path>).listFiles().length

… for example:
 final int countFilesFound = Objects.requireNonNull( path.toFile( ).listFiles( ( folder , name ) -> !name.startsWith( "." ) ) ).length;

… has a few issues:

❌ Counts nested folders as files. I want to ignore nested folders.
✅ As for ignoring hidden files, I can pass a lambda ( folder , name ) -> !name.startsWith( "." ) which does work.
❌ I have to convert my Path object to a File to make this work, which seems silly to me, but no big deal.
❌ Is indirect and complicated, having to create an array and then ask for its length.

Files.list
This Answer shows code using Java NIO features of Java 8+.
try (Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get("your/path/here"))) {
    long count = files.count();
}

I adapted that to this partial solution:
final long count;
try
{
    count = Files.list( path ).filter( Files :: isRegularFile ).count( );
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    throw new RuntimeException( e );
}

Issues include:

❌ Having to wrap in the try-catch. Workable, but wow so many lines for such a simple goal of counting files.
❌ The .list call has a warning in my IDE that I need a try-with-resources here. I cannot understand needing to call close on a stream that has a terminal operation (.count here). I have never seen that issue in all my time using streams.
✅ Successfully ignores folders.

Is there any simple way to get a list and/or count of real files found directly in a folder?

what kind of folders are not nested folders?

@jsotola ??? "nested folders" are folders found within the target folder.  If I look in "Wine Sales 2024" folder, I want to ignore any folders within, such as "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", and "Q4". I do not want a recursive search through all the folders that may exist within my target folder.

The try/catch is unavoidable.  Any operation that accesses a directory or file can throw exceptions.  For example, you may not have permission to list the directory.  Or you may encounter hard disk error or network error (for a remotely mounted FS) on reading the directory or the file metadata.

@StephenC The first example with File#listFiles call does not require the catch ( IOException e ).

Terminal operations don't close the stream: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381329/do-terminal-operations-on-streams-close-the-source

Scanning with more complex criteria is much easier with Files.find, or Files.walkFileTree. Both allow you to limit depth of search and present your callbacks with attributes information. Not near a PC so can't copy/paste examples

@BasilBourque - Well yea ... but that is because the File API is old and clunky and you shouldn't use it ... and it swallows exceptions ... and you probably shouldn't be simply ignoring things like "you can't access that directory"

@StephenC Understood. Thank you.

You can't really escape exception handling here (unless the API swallows exception, like the old one), operations with files and folders can always fail.
Technically you could not deal with the exceptions, using lomboks @SneakyThrows or something similar, but it's better to handle it, an IOException is a real possibility.
The docs explicitly state that streams, whose source is an IO channel must be closed:

Streams have a BaseStream.close() method and implement AutoCloseable, but nearly all stream instances do not actually need to be closed after use. Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel (such as those returned by Files.lines(Path, Charset)) will require closing. Most streams are backed by collections, arrays, or generating functions, which require no special resource management. (If a stream does require closing, it can be declared as a resource in a try-with-resources statement.)

Your best bet is try-with-resources to close the stream and handle the exception together:
final long count;
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Path.of("some path"))) {
  count = stream
          .peek(path -> System.out.println("debug current path - " + path))
          .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
          .count();
  System.out.println(count);
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
}

You could combine the old API with streams, in order to not handle the exception, but that's probably not good idea, because it will be swallowed instead, all File.listFiles() methods do so:

Returns:
An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

final long countFilesFound = Arrays.stream(Objects.requireNonNull(path.toFile().listFiles((folder, name) -> !name.startsWith("."))))
            .filter(File::isFile)
            .count();

Also, this approach is less readable, IMHO.

For whatever it may be worth, I settled on the following code, given the lessons learned from the Answer by Chaosfire and the Comments.
This code:

Uses try-with-resources syntax to automatically close the directory opened by Files.list.
Filters out items hidden Unix-style by prefixing the name with a FULL STOP character (.).
Filters out directories by way of Files#isRegularFile method.

This code allows the default behavior of following any symbolic link to its original file.
public static long countFilesInFolder ( final Path path )
{
    Objects.requireNonNull( path );
    try ( Stream < Path > list = Files.list( path ) ; )
    {
        return
                list
                        .filter( ( Path thePath ) -> !thePath.getFileName( ).toString( ).startsWith( "." ) )  // Exclude Unix-style hidden files.
                        .filter( Files :: isRegularFile )  // Exclude nested folders.
                        .count( );
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        throw new RuntimeException( e );
    }
}

We need not test if the passed Path object erroneously represents a file rather than a folder. The Files.list method already makes that check, throwing a java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException.
Example usage:
final Path path = Paths.get( "/Users/some_user/Sales/Wine Sales 2024" );
final long count = WhateverClass.countFilesInFolder( path );

Given the example in the Question, where we ignore the Q… folders, and we ignore the macOS-specific .DS_Store file, the result would be:

1

